# Express: Restore form values on failed signup after redirect

Tags: forms, node.js, validation, express, pug

So I'm working on a signup form. If the user's input is invalid, I redirect user to `/signup` and `flash` an error.

```
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        for (var field in err.errors) {
            var error = err.errors[field].message;
            req.flash('error', error);
        }
        res.redirect('/signup');
    } else {
            ...do stuff...
```

Works well.

Not, what I want is, that the values of the form are restored. Right now, the values are blank after the redirect. I tried looking at passing the `user` into my jade template during `redirect`, but that doesn't work.

Since it's a signup form with username, password and email, I am looking for a secure approach. I looked at storing the details in `req.session` but 1) I don't know how to fit all that in my jade template 2) I don't know how secure that is.

Comment: Some javascript validation might save the user from submitting the form with bad data

Comment: No yeah saving the data isn't the issue, but how do I display it? `redirect` doesn't work.

Comment: still not fixed. i'm thinking of moving to an API based design, but ajax requests, if this doesn't work out.